# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server query which is returning `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

```
(
    @numberRecords int,
    @date varchar(12)
)

AS
SET ROWCOUNT @numberRecords
SELECT re.ID, re.RecentChangeTypeID, re.LogID, re.RevisionID
FROM RecentChanges re
    FULL OUTER JOIN Revisions rev
        ON re.RevisionID = rev.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN Logs lg
        ON re.LogID = lg.ID
WHERE convert(datetime, rev.Timestamp) >= '@date' OR
      convert(datetime, lg.Timestamp) >= '@date';
RETURN
```

The `date` parameter returns a string value in the format "dd-MM-yyyy". What may be the cause?

Comment: why not store rev.Timestamp and lg.Timestamp as datetime columns?

Comment: +1, @KM. - Nothing good ever comes from storing dates or numbers as strings

Comment: Yes, both timestamps are stored as datetime

Comment: @JNK, sorting problems, conversion problems, and invalid data!

Comment: @chrisportelli then why are you `convert`ing them?

Comment: if they are already datetime, I'd rewrite the query to use a UNION (remove the OR) and get index usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your `@date` parameter inside single quotes - it's being interpreted as a string instead of as a parameter.

As written you are trying to make `'@date'` a `datetime` which won't parse.

That being said, you should probably make the input parameter a `datetime` in the first place.

Comment: +1, the code is comparing the table columns against the sting literal "@date".  You need to compare the table columns against the variable @date.  If you say `MyColumn='abc'` you are comparing your column against the constant string "abc".  if you say `MyColumn='@abc'` you are still comparing you column against the a constant string "@abc".  if you say `MyColumn=@abc` you are comparing your column against the value within the `@abc` variable.

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes as @JNK has described to make your query work.  However, for possibly much better performance (index usage) try this query (if you have indexes on the columns `Revisions.Timestamp` and `Logs.Timestamp`) :

```
SELECT 
    re.ID, re.RecentChangeTypeID, re.LogID, re.RevisionID
FROM RecentChanges         re
    INNER JOIN Revisions   rev ON re.RevisionID = rev.ID
WHERE rev.Timestamp >= @date
UNION
SELECT 
    re.ID, re.RecentChangeTypeID, re.LogID, re.RevisionID
FROM RecentChanges    re
    INNER JOIN Logs   lg ON re.LogID = lg.ID
WHERE lg.Timestamp >= @date
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me, at first glance, that you are converting to datetime, not from it. I am assuming rev.Timestamp is a datetime already, while your @date is a varchar(12)...so SQL Server is complaining that it can't compare a datetime to a string...

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer means...You're basically talking in circles.

Comment: no, i'm not. your convert statement converts a datetime to another datetime, takes the result and compares it to a varchar(12)